# MVC routing - different urls to the same action

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js

I have backbone.js framework at client side that performs POSTs to the following urls to create/update some entity:
`controller/action` - for creating a new
`controller/action/{id}` - for updating an existing one

I want a single action `Save` to process both operations and perform entity creation/updation depending on the Id value of the incoming model that is listed below:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON model being posted looks like: `{ id: 123, name: "some name" }`
Thus I want to have a single controller action `Save` and to tune the route table so it accepts both `controller/action` and `controller/action/{id}` requests for the action Save.
I've racked my brain trying to achieve it.
My action looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(TestModel model)
{
    // do something
}
```

The following route configs didn't make it work:
1.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Test.Save1",
        url: "api/test/data",
        defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Save" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Test.Save2",
        url: "api/test/data/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Save", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Works for /api/test/data, returns 404 on posting to /api/test/data/123

2.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Test.Save",
        url: "api/test/data/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Save", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Works for /api/test/data, returns 404 on posting to /api/test/data/123

3.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Test.Save",
        url: "api/test/data/{*pathInfo}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Save" }
    );
```

Works for /api/test/data, returns 404 on posting to /api/test/data/123

I probably can guess why it gives error, but more important question is how to make it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just post both to /api/test/data: "save" will have a null id, "edit" won't.

Comment: Please expand on your answer.  As-is, it is very hard to see whether this solves the problem or not. I have fixed punctuation.